# How to prevent iPad Pro from dropping to 1Hz for touch events in UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt, ipad, uiview

I am developing an iPad app with Qt which implements UIView. I have customized touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded to read Apple Pencil events, but for some reason a recent iOS update has changed the sample rate for apple pencil (and all touch events?) to around 1Hz. This is obviously a bummer.

I read somewhere (I forget where) that the sample rate decrease is to save battery and you have to update the view or something similar to get the refresh rate to increase to the full amount? Or is there another way to fix it?

I fairly clever but am a total novice with objectiveC.

Thank you!